# Run Automatic Integration Tests on Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm

My team has developed a kubernetes cluster. And we have tested it manually using `kubectl` command line. These test cases are related to for example:

- Pods
- Services,LoadBalancer etc.
- Deployments
- Horizontal Pod Scaling
- Rollback Deployments
- Ingress Controller
- Helm - the package manager for kubernetes
- Persistence volume and persistence volume claims.
- DNS

Link for above manual testcases: [Kubernetes DOCS](https://kubernetes.io/docs)

I have found a Github resource to run integration tests using automation.
Please refer to this link for more information: [Run Integration test cases on kubernetes](https://github.com/thtanaka/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/devel/testing.md#integration-tests)

But seems that i am unable to figure it out how to run them. Process mentioned by Github Resource is confusing and not clear.

I have searched for blogs for whole day and seems like they were helpful but not much. My question is has anyone have run the integration test cases on their kubernetes cluster using automation?

If **yes** can you please share the best resource and steps to follow up.

Adding more information i have searched everywhere and found a Github repository
[Official Python client library for kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python), and i am going to try with this.

Answer (score 0):

Give a read-through of [Sonobuoy](https://heptio.github.io/sonobuoy/). It runs a conformance test on a Kubernetes cluster and also allows you to do some specific tests using it's [plugin architecture](https://heptio.github.io/sonobuoy/latest/plugins.html).